# MQL query to get all properties for the particular MID in Freebase

Tags: semantic-web, freebase, mql

Take a look at this MID "/m/02r4n63" of [**freebase**](http://www.freebase.com/). Question is how to get all the properties related to this MID.
[**Freebase page**](http://www.freebase.com/m/02r4n63?any=%2Fcommon%2Ftopic%5d) for this MID.
I need to extract all the properties like director, producer, starring, etc from this page.

I tried these queries in [**endpoint**](http://www.freebase.com/query)

```
{
    "*": null,
    "type": "/film/film",
    "id": "/m/02r4n63"
}
```

**Output** of above query gives properties related to `/film/film` only and gives `starring list` as `null`.

I tried this one

```
[{
    "master_property": {
        "name": null,
        "id": null
    },
    "source": {
        "mid": "/m/02r4n63"
    },
    "target": null,
    "target_value": null,
    "type": "/type/link"
}]
```

**Output** of above query misses out `/film/starring` property.

I also tried

```
{
    "id": "/m/01jrbb",
    "/type/reflect/any_master": [{
        "id": null,
        "link": {
            "master_property": {
                "id": null,
                "name": null
            },
            "target": null,
            "target_value": null
        }
    }],
    "/type/reflect/any_value": [{
        "link": {
            "master_property": {
                "id": null,
                "name": null
            },
            "target": null,
            "target_value": null
        }
    }],
    "/type/reflect/any_reverse": [{
        "id": null,
        "link": {
            "master_property": {
                "reverse_property": {
                    "id": null,
                    "key": null,
                    "name": null
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

But again it misses out properties like `Description`.

I want to cover all the properties.
I tried the [topic search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview) already. That's the output I want. But I want it through MQL query as I need the names of the properties too.

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Topic API is the best way to get all information about a given topic:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02r4n63

You can get the name of a property using MQL e.g.:

```
{
  "name": null,
  "id": "/film/film/starring"
}
```

which will return "Performances".  Of course, these are mostly going to be properties that you've seen before, so you'll probably want to either cache them or just pre-populate a static list.

If you want "starring", you can just split the key returned and take the last slash (/) delimited segment.

Comment: marris : Thankz for ur answer. keys are returned as "/film/film/starring". What I wanted is name of these properties such as "starring" as a key instead of "/film/film/starring"

Comment: I tried this one "expensive query like `"*":[{[{}]}]" It wont work

Comment: The Topic API is really the right way to do this.  If you need the labels/names for properties, you can pre-fetch them separately or fetch and cache them.